# Which one of these approaches to casting is the most effective?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been wondering about that for quite a while now.

```
if(something is MyType){
 var item = something as MyType;
}
```

Or

```
var item = something as MyType;
if(item != null){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd version

```
var item = something as MyType;

if (item != null) {
  ...
}
```

is better: just *one* type conversion (`as`) not two (`is` and then `as`).

The 1st version (a *bit modified*) can be used for `struct` that are not *nullable*:

```
// you can't put "as" for struct, i.e "something as int"
if (something is int) {
  int item = (int) something; // note changed type conversion
  ...
}
```

Comment: Then what is the poing of the is operator anyways if we could use as always. That means it exists solely for bool checks.

Comment: `is` is used to test if instance is a type *without* type conversion `if (value is ObsoleteClass) {...recomend user to update the routine...}`; another case is when you have to check for `struct`: `if (x is int) {int v = (int)x; ...}`

Comment: If you are certain of your cast, for example in the case of boxing a struct, then the `(MyType)something` is the fastest. - the reason for the `is` operator is that it is faster than the actual cast operation - the `as` operator is the slowest, the explicit cast is the fastest, and the `is` is a fast check for it being an instance of the type, without actually converting the type.

Comment: That makes sense now :) Thanks